# php5.6 cannot fetch a session variable and THEN delete the variable

Tags: php, session, php-5.6

Today I have a bit of an odd one.

I have found out that apparently I cannot use a session variable AND THEN destroy it (without destroying the entire session.)

Let me explain. If I do this, for example:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['var'])) {
    $var = $_SESSION['var'];
    unset($_SESSION['var']);
}
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo "var: $var";
```

The result is "var" is empty both as $var and as a key is $_SESSION.

However, if you comment out the unsetting part, the var is in both $var as well as in the $_SESSION array.

even the much fancier:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['var'])) {
    $var = array_splice($_SESSION, array_search('var', array_keys($_SESSION)), 1);   
}
```

seems to have the exact same problem.

This is sooooo odd.

What can I even do when presented with such a weeeeiiird behavior?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I just did the obvious wise-ass thing to do:

```
$session_copy = $_SESSION;

if (isset($session_copy['var'])) {
    $var = $session_copy['var'];
    unset($_SESSION['var']);
}
```

Yep, **doesn't work either.**

Comment: Can't seem to [replicate the problem](https://3v4l.org/1KGtX) from 5.2.3 through 7.4.0.

Comment: seems to depend on php settings as pointed out in the response

Comment: Do you `session_start()` somewhere we don't see?

Comment: Correct, I do so in an included file.

Answer (score -1):

This is answered in the php docs here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php#85448

> Please note that if you have register_globals to On, global variables
>   associated to $_SESSION variables are references, so this may lead to
>   some weird situations.

It is a weird situation, but not undocumented. I'm sure you can dig further if you want to know more about why php handles session variables this way.

Comment: yes I need to persist data between two requests but I cannot use request parameters, therefore, I was hoping I could use the session.

Comment: After the second request, however, my session variables become useless clutter and could lead to bugs so I need to remove them.

Comment: You should ask that as another, specific question. P.S. thanks for teaching me something about php today, didn't know this before.