# Recovering a session key and then deleting it. (php5.6) (workaround)

Tags: php, session, php-5.6

guys,

As I showed here: [php5.6 cannot fetch a session variable and THEN delete the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59219215/php5-6-cannot-fetch-a-session-variable-and-then-delete-the-variable)

Apparently you cannot use a session key, and then delete said key.

So I need a workaround.

Here's what I've tried so far, and unbelievably does NOT work:

- A SQL key-value store. Doesn't work either, reading the key from mysql and then deleting it results in losing it.
- Unbelievably a file system based secondary session store does not work either (I am foaming at the mouth at this point.). Here's the code for my secondary session key value store:

```
<?php


class Session2 {
  public $uid;

  public function __construct($uid = '') {
    if (!$uid) {
      $this->uid = session_id();
    } else {
      $this->uid = $uid;
    }

  }

  private function keyPath($key) {
    return "session2/session-{$this->uid}-$key";
  }

  public function setKey($key, $value) {
    $file = fopen($this->keyPath($key), 'w');

    fwrite($file, $value);
    fclose($file);
  }

  public function getKey($key) {
    $file = fopen($this->keyPath($key), 'r');

    $value = fread($file, 2500);
    fclose($file);

    return $value;
  }

  public function wipeKey($key) {
    @unlink($this->keyPath($key));
  }

  public function hasKey($key) {
    return file_exists($this->keyPath($key));
  }
}
```

And an example of setting:

```
  $sess2 = new Session2();

  if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $sess2->setKey('id', $_GET['id']);
  }
```

and recovering:

```
    $sess2 = new Session2();

    if ($sess2->hasKey('id')) {
      $id = $sess2->getKey('id');

      $sess2->wipeKey('id');
    }
```

Are PHP sessions just cursed? what do I even do now?

Comment: Have you tried not unlinking the "session" file and made sure it contains what it should? (Upgrade to PHP7?)

Comment: If I dont unlink it it works fine. Which, of course, also means that the content is correct.

Comment: also I cannot upgrade to php 7, my client will not pay for it.